# Bayesian optimization for hyperparameter tuning using mlr3

Tags: r, bayesian, hyperparameters, mlr3

Are there any hyperparameter tuners using Bayesian optimization within the `mlr3` ecosystem?
In particular as an argument in the wrapper function

```
tuner = tnr("grid_search", resolution = 10)
```

?

Otherwise, what would be a recommended tuning method supported by `mlr3`?

**UPDATE:**
I tried following @Sebastian's [mlr3mbo link](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3mbo) -- in particular the "Simple Tuning Example Using Defaults" section.

However, when I tried to use it in tune_nested

```
rr = tune_nested(
    method = "mbo", 
    task,
    learner=lrn("surv.cv_glmnet",  nfolds=3, type.measure = "C", alpha = to_tune(0.01, 1)) ,
    inner_resampling = rsmp("cv", folds = 10), 
    outer_resampling = rsmp("cv", folds = 10), 
    measure = msr("surv.cindex"), 
    term_evals = 20
    )
```

I get the error:

```
Error in auto_tuner(method, learner, inner_resampling, measure, term_evals,  : 
  Assertion on 'method' failed: Must be element of set {'cmaes','design_points','gensa','grid_search','irace','nloptr','random_search'}, but is 'mbo'.
Calls: tune_nested ... auto_tuner -> assert_choice -> makeAssertion -> mstop
```

**UPDATE2**: after using `devtools::install_github("mlr-org/mlr3mbo@add_tuner")`  as @Sebastian helpfully suggested, I get instead the following error message:

```
Error in .__ParamSet__search_space(self = self, private = private, super = super,  : 
  Assertion on 'names(values)' failed: Must have names.
```

Does `alpha = to_tune(0.01, 1)` within `lrn()` not sufficiently specify the required name and value range of the HP `alpha`?

Is there any way around this? Thanks!

**SOLUTION**:
Thanks to @Sebastian who fixed this -- in his comment:

> manually define the `search_space` like `search_space = ps(alpha = p_dbl(0.01, 1))` and then pass it as the `search_space` argument to
> `tune_nested`

Super!

Comment: I think you are looking for is described in [their book](https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/optimization.html#tuning).

Comment: Also bayesian optimization can be done with [mlr3mbo](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3mbo)

Comment: Thanks @Kat, I have actually read that section! However as far as I understand that is BO is not included? I even read the non-linear option tnr("nloptr"). Is my understanding of that book section correct?

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian! I will give mlr3mbo a try!

Comment: @Sebastian I tried to follow the mlr3mbo link but please see the update I added to the question -- would you have any advice? Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that mlr3mbo is not yet properly connected to mlr3tuning (This is not a difficult thing to do I assume). I hope I get time to look at it properly in the evening today and provide you with a solution.

Comment: I did this quickly and it seems to be working, but no guarantee. Just install the branch by running devtools::install_github("mlr-org/mlr3mbo@add_tuner")

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian, it does starts running but for some reason I keep getting the error 
```Error in .__ParamSet__search_space(self = self, private = private, super = super,  : 
  Assertion on 'names(values)' failed: Must have names.```
?

Comment: PS. @Sebastian I presume this has to do with the ```paradox``` package? Also does the ```alpha = to_tune(0.01, 1)``` within ```lrn()```, not specify the required name and value range of the HP ```alpha```? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example, that makes it easier to help you :) You can use the reprex R package for that

Comment: ok actually I could preproduce the error, I will provide more information later

Comment: Does the error still occur if you manually define the `search_space` like `search_space = ps(alpha = p_dbl(0.01, 1))` and then pass it as the `search_space` argument to `tune_nested`?

Comment: +1 !!! Thanks @Sebastian!! This worked! I have also added your comment to main post in case it helps others. Thanks again!

Comment: I am pretty sure this is a bug and your approach should have worked, possibly I messed something up when adding the MBO tuner. I will let you know when it works properly

Comment: Hi @Sebastian, sorry for bothering you again. I have been running the resampling with HP tuning (as above) since our exchange -- for several days now -- and it still hasn't finished (big dataset). The job is being run on a cluster and I am not sure how to optimise the computation (sorry about my ignorance!). I did not set nthread and from inspection it defaulted to 1... In case it's helpful, the node I am using has 16 cores +192GB RAM 10 Gigabit data network... Grateful for any pointers, thanks! :)

Comment: ^In terms of parallelising properly? I also see that only 1 core is used... Is this a cluster issue that I should resolve with the IT supprt? I am running models using mlr3learners surv.cv_glmnet and surv.xgboost. outer and inner resampling 5 folds each and term_eval=20. (As far as I understand term_eval just means the number of parameter combos evaluated -- is this correct?) Thanks!

Comment: Ah I think I should use 
```future::plan(list(future::tweak("multisession", workers = N1), #outer
                  future::tweak("multisession", workers = N2) #inner
                  )) ```
where N1 and N2 are ideally divisors of 5, so 5 or 1 in this example... Do you agree? 
Thanks @Sebastian

Comment: This chapter might help you https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/technical.html

Comment: I dont have a lot of experience with parallelization so you probably should ask someone else.

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian I think I've got it to do multiprocessing now :) Thanks for the link!

Comment: Hi @Sebastian -- for some reason, when using mlr3mbo recently, it's been throwing up the error: ```Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘mlr3mbo’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘mlr3tuning’ 0.9.0 is already loaded, but >= 0.9.0.9000 is required``` ? But when I tried to update mlr3tuning via install.packages(), I still only get mlr3tuning_0.9.0.

Comment: You can install the github version with `devtools::install_github("mlr-org/mlr3tuning")`. Alternatively to make your life easier until the Mbo Tuner is properly implemented would be to use another tuner from `mlr3tuning`

Comment: When you called `install.packages(mlr3tuning)` you installed the CRAN version of `mlr3tuning`, but mlr3mbo requires 0.9.0.9 (dev-version)

Comment: Also the bug with the to_tune has been fixed. If you install the devel version of mlr3verse it should be working

Comment: I think things are working now :) Thanks @Sebastian ! One last question: is there a reference for how the optimiser works, eg the maths behind it? I searched and only found https://mlr3mbo.mlr-org.com/reference/mlr_optimizers_mbo.html which doesn't have many details...

Answer (score 0):

Just checking in to add a few comments and answer your latest question @Alex:
A minor note on the error:

```
Error in .__ParamSet__search_space(self = self, private = private, super = super,  : 
  Assertion on 'names(values)' failed: Must have names.
```

This was rather caused due to old `bbotk`/`paradox` versions that have been fixed upstream and you most likely should no longer encounter any errors anymore. The manual fix is no longer needed.

The BO Tuner will live in `mlr3mbo` and a PR will be merged soon.

In general `mlr3mbo` is slowly but steady getting to a point where it can be considered stable and will be pushed to CRAN. I do agree that some documentation is still missing. Also, one or two gallery posts about the inner workings of `mlr3mbo` will be provided in the near future.

Regarding:

```
One last question: is there a reference for how the optimiser works, eg the maths behind it? I searched and only found mlr3mbo.mlr-org.com/reference/mlr_optimizers_mbo.html which doesn't have many details.
```

All current implementations are somewhat standard/basic BO stuff, therefore we currently did not included detailed descriptions of the algorithms (but we may do this in the future).

(sequential) (single-criteria) BO (as e.g., implemented in `bayesopt_ego`) works by fitting a `Surrogate` model to your evaluated points, learning the relationship between inputs and outputs. Based on an acquisition function `AcqFunction` (relying on this surrogate) that encodes for each potential next candidate to evaluate the gain in evaluation (i.e., how much can I expect to improve my solution if I evaluate this candidate) you find the next point to query, evaluate it and update your archive of evaluated points and start over again with refitting the surrogate.

I highlighted the respective classes/functions and most of them include references to standard papers where you can learn more about the maths/technical details.

Also, if you find `mlr3mbo` useful or have any further comments/questions, feel free to also communicate with us via GitHub https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3mbo. Issues/open questions etc. are welcome!